# Copy changes origin/development to origin/master

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I have this history graph in Sourcetree:
[Sourcetree graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyh3v.png)

How can I copy the last commits from origin/development to origin/master branch?

The second question is: what are the meanings of the symbols "origin/development", "master", "origin/master", and "origin/HEAD" in the picture?

Comment: `master` is your local copy of this branch, `origin/master` is a remote tracking branch will follows the true `master` branch in the repository.  You should review a good Git tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To push changes from development branch to master:

1. git push origin development

This syncs the local development branch with the one on the server.

From GitLab, use to tools to create a Pull Request, and then merge it into master:

1. Create pull request from development branch
2. Merge development branch into master

origin/development is a reference to a branch called development which is located on a remote repository called "origin".  When you work locally, you can push changes to your remote repository via:

```
git push origin `<branch>`
```

This will work for a new local branch that you create. To setup a remote tracking branch for an existing branch on the server, you would run another command first. For example, if there is an existing remote branch called "development":

```
git branch development origin/development
```

If you want to setup origin/development to be an upstream branch from (local)/development, then:

```
git branch -u development origin/development
```

This allows you to push and pull from origin, without explicitly specifying 'origin':

i.e.

```
git push
git pull
```

Instead of:

```
git push origin development
git pull origin development
```

Answer (score 1):

To incorporate the commits which are on the branch "origin/development" into "master", you will need to "merge" origin/development into master. You accomplish this by checking out your destination branch (master) with the command `git checkout master`.

Then you perform the merge with the command `git merge origin/development`. You may have to resolve merge conflicts before this is successful.

In answer to your second question: The symbols are Git "branches" of your source tree. origin/master and origin/development are what are known as remote branches. They represent the last known revisions of a remote Git repository - in this case "origin". Your local branches master and development are your local copies of these branches.

As you don't seem to have a grasp of the entry-level concepts of Git, I highly recommend you read the [Git Book](http://Pro%20Git%20book) - it will ground you in the basics, and then build up to the more advanced concepts.

Comment: There won't be any merge conflicts, as `origin/master` does not contain any commits that are not already in `origin/development`.

Comment: Yeah, I know @DavidScarlett - I just figure it's best to mention that merge conflicts are a thing now, because it's bound to happen next time. There's a decent chance that the OP hasn't done a `fetch` in a while either, so the next question will probably be regarding how to resolve them.

Answer (score 1):

`origin/development` and `origin/master` are remote tracking branches that represent the state of the `development` and `master` branches on the `origin` server. You don't directly modify these, rather they get updated when you `pull` or `fetch` from `origin`.

To update them, you would commit the changes you want into your local `development` or `master` branch and push those changes to `origin`. But first, do a `pull` or `fetch` to make sure that you're working on the latest versions of both.

In this case, an easy shortcut would be to change your branch to `master`, `reset --hard` to `origin/development`, which forces the current state of your local `master` to that of `origin/development`, and then push to origin, which will cause `origin/master` to receive all the additional commits (from `origin/development`) that are now present in your `master`. Note that this only works because `origin/master` does not contain any commits that are not already in `origin/development`.